# How to control js promise flow when one function needs only 1 promise resolved and the other needs all promises resolved?

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, promise

I have 2 web service endpoints that I'm trying to fulfill with promises. What I need to accomplish is once endpoint1 is finished, I need to load some components, and once both endpoint1 and endpoint2 are done, I need to load some other components. I want both requests to be sent off at once, but run some code when the first one is done and some other code when all requests are finished.

endpoint1 -> function1

endpoint1 + endpoint2 -> function2

I'm using axios as the web service request library.

I've tried:

```js
Promise.all([axios.get(endpoint1), axios.get(endpoint2)]).then(...)
```

But this will wait for both endpoints to return before I can proceed forcing one branch of the code to wait unnecessarily. I can use:

```js
axios.get(endpoint1).then(...)
```

But I don't know how to ensure both are resolved for the other branch of code. I can get it working by sending the endpoint1 request twice (once with `Promise.all` and once on its own) but that seems inelegant. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do like;

```
let p1 = axios.get(endpoint1),
    p2 = axios.get(endpoint2);

p1.then(function1);
promise.all([p1,p2])
       .then(function2);
```

Obviously `function2(...rs)` can access the resolutions of both `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: I would use `.allSettled()` in place of `.all()`

Comment: @AnantAnandGupta Sure that's another possibility which depends on how yıou would like to handle the exceptions.

Comment: sorry no offense here, just going with the question as OP was asking for all promises resolved in her question.